# Which version of ECMAScript (Year) is used in HCL Domino V10, V11, V12?

Tags: javascript, lotus-domino

From Help Domino Designer:

> JavaScript language elements (JavaScript)  The JavaScript language
> elements are based on the ECMAScript Language Specification Standard
> ECMA-262 (see
> http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm).
> The JavaScript described here applies to the server-side interpreter.
> Client-side scripts are interpreted by the browser.

But not information about the year.

In which version of Domino can I use the "class" keyword, for ssjs library like in ECMA-262, 6th edition, June 2015?

I use Domino Designer V11. Maybe need some additional Designer settings for using `class` keywords?